# ncurses.h is not found, even though it is on the search path

Tags: compiling, configure, ncurses

I have installed `ncurses` package from source, and now I have

```
$HOME/local/include/ncurses/curses.h
$HOME/local/include/ncurses/ncurses.h
```

on my filesystem. I have also set up the search pathes so that

```
$ echo $C_INCLUDE_PATH
$HOME/local/include:
$ echo $CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
$HOME/local/include:
```

(i have eddited the output of echo to replace home path with `$HOME`)

however, when i `./configure` another package i get

```
checking ncurses.h usability... no
checking ncurses.h presence... no
```

what's the problem that the system cannot detect `curses` installation?

Comment: make sure your two paths you mentioned at the start do not have the inlcude typo on the filesystem.

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx i fixed the typo in the question, thanks for pointing out

Comment: I found this guide really helpful for statically compiling tmux 1.9 on fedora 19: http://pyther.net/2014/03/building-tmux-1-9a-statically/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

configure scripts produce config.log (in the same folder) files which contain all the details on the tests it ran. They're not particularly easy to read, but open it up and search for "checking ncurses.h usability". Look at what went wrong with the small test program it tried to compile.

My guess is, it doesn't care about $C_INCLUDE_PATH and you'll need to pass it to the build system in a different matter. configure options (eg. --includedir=$HOME/local/include) and $CFLAGS + $CXXFLAGS + $CPPFLAGS  (adding -I$HOME/local/include) come to mind.

Comment: I did `./configure CFLAGS=-I/home/w381833/local/include/ncurses CXXFLAGS=-I/home/w381833/local/include/ncurses` and I got `configure: WARNING: curses.h: accepted by the compiler, rejected by the preprocessor!
configure: WARNING: curses.h: proceeding with the compiler's result`. I think i am doing something wrong or that something is missing in here

Comment: add CPPFLAGS=-I/home/w381833/local/include/ncurses (for the preprocessor).

Comment: perfect, worked like charm, thanks @lynxlynxlynx